# About (sender, instance, created, **kwargs) parameter. How it's assigned

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

I'm new to python in general and while I was going through a tutorial it teaches about signals.

I've been trying to figured how this function works, as in how (sender, instance, created, **kwargs) is assigned to? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

So if a post is saved it triggers this vvv

> receiver(post_save, sender=User)

in this case `User` gets assigned to `sender`, since `sender=User` easy.

Now, as for the second parameter, instance, it shows in the very last line of the function. `user=instance`. from my understanding of function, and parameter, should it all be assigned WHEN the function is CALLED? in this case when the receiver signal is triggered and `create_profile` is called, `instance` and `created` has no value yet.... correct? As for `created`, why does it have to be a parameter? since it's checking if CREATED.

Does (instance, created) have an in built....functionality in it? since from what I get those three are placeholders and it needs to be assigned a value in order to do anything. When does `instance` and `created` get assigned? And what is 'if created'? I understand that means if the aaccount is created but HOW does the created parameter hold a value to work in this if created to work?

In the future, if I encounter similar problems such as this...how can I figure out how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters mean the following:

`sender`: The model class which the signal was called with.

`instance`: The instance of a `User`, whether this was created or updated.

`created`: A Boolean to determine if the `User` was updated or created.

When the signal is called, none of the parameters will be empty.

I found this information on the [official Django docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#post-save).

Comment: THANK YOUSO MUCH! I made your answer the official answer thqnk you!!